# Invalid string: control characters in github action - jq

Tags: json, github, yaml, jq

Good Afternoon all,

I am presenting the following problem.

`new_ecdsa_config.json` looks something like:

```json
{
  "certificate": "value long string
                          multine"
}
```

When I run the github action for reading the value

```yaml
  - name: Add new ECDSA to Organization
    run: |
      cat new_ecdsa_config.json | jq '.'
```

I get the following error:

```
parse error: Invalid string: control characters from U+0000 through U+001F must be escaped at line 26, column 53
Error: Process completed with exit code 4.
```

Any ideas??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you described the problem on [github](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/issues/1049#issuecomment-1197458462), you gave this as the example:

```
{
  "certificate": "value long string
                          multine"
}
```

As the error message says, that is not valid JSON. (You can double-check this at jsonlint.com if you like.)

If you want the JSON representation of a multiline string, you'd have to escape the newline, e.g. along the lines of:

```
{
  "certificate": "value long string\nmultiline"
}
```